# Ensure that parse afterSave fires

Tags: parse-platform

I am wondering how to ensure that Parse afterSave runs and does not fail for a request limit exceeded error. My application design requires me to charge a credit card (that has already been authorized) after another user performs an irreversible action.

One solution I thought of was to call the function to run again (in the `error` callback on this specific failure), but this would not work with afterSave (for the simple reason that it can only be called after a save and not independently, I think.)

Or, is afterSave a "fire and forget" -- and it should not be used for things that need reliability?

Thanks in advance for your ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`afterSave` is not a fire-and-forget method. It fires in every single case if the target object gets an objectId from the Parse.com server. On the other hand, you may use the `beforeSave` method if you want it to be fired even in case if the object don't get saved on the DB. Hope this helps.